# TempData se borra al navegar por otras vistas sin recargar la vista original

Tags: c#, .net, mvc

tengo un proyecto en MVC C#, y al entrar a una vista y guardar una lista de datos en un TempData, al abrir otras vistas en otras pestañas, ese TempData se elimina 30 segundos despues de estar navegando por otras vistas, y al consultar ese TempData, me regresa null, lo raro es que no utilizo ese mismo identificador en otras vistas.

Comment: Hola JoeStark96, bienvenido, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código y los mensajes de error (si es que los recibes) en formato texto, y que nos expliques en que falla, mira Cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada. aprovecha y haz el recorrido de Bienvenida para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!